# Some eigenvalue living in some interval

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $ A = (a_{ij})$ be a matrix of size $ n^2 $ such that $ a_{ij} > 0$. Let $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n ) $ and$ y = (y_1,\ldots,y_n) = Ax$.  Show that there exist an eigenvalue $\lambda $ of A, such that:
$$
\lambda  \in \left[ {\min \left\{ {\frac{{y_i }}
{{x_i }}} \right\}_{i = 1}^n ,\max \left\{ {\frac{{y_i }}
{{x_i }}} \right\}_{i = 1}^n } \right].
$$
I have no idea how to do it :S!!

Someone knows this result or related? or some solution?

Comment: Nothing special about $\mathbf A$?

Comment: You may want to look into the Perron-Frobenius theorem. I believe this problem is an exercise in Meyer's "Matrix Analysis."

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very like the [Frobenius-Perron Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) The standard Frobenius-Perron Theorem can be thought of as asserting the result you want, but only for the special case $(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(1,\dots,1)$. (Multiplying by this vector gives us the row sums of the Theorem.)  However,  we can use Frobenius-Perron to obtain information from $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with positive $x_i$.

If the $x_i$ are positive, we can modify your matrix $A$ by multiplying the $i$-th column of $A$ by $x_i$. Then if $A'$ is the modified matrix, and $e$ is the vector of all $1$'s, we have $Ax= A'e$. Now standard Frobenius-Perron, applied to $A'$, should give what you want.

Comment: Sorry for ask , but I did not understand the problem so well.  When he take some vector "x" this vector is fixed? or not? I don´t understand well this, we never seen that theorem , but I can use it. But I did not understand what do you mean, with taking the vector (1,...1) sorry for ask something so stupid )=

Comment: As a start, do look at the Wikipedia article. Look carefully at the inequality for the largest eigenvalue.